# CSS Rendering Issue in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I was trying to design this site:
http://bylc.org/summit2012/

When I was working offline in my pc everything was alright. But when I uploaded it in the server, the problems started to show up.

When I try to load the file for the first time everything seems to load correctly but after reloading the page the carousal stops working and the right part (side bar) of the page gets down and renders some text in different color and font. Also there becomes a little space between the carousal and the side bar.

I've tried everything in my knowledge. tried X-UA-Compatible, stopped all javascript in the page. But nothing did work. :( Could anyone please check and help.

Comment: Everything works well in IE 8 but not in Chrome / Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Disabling scripts altogether caused the errors to occur on initial load as well as on subsequent loads, which leads me to believe it has something to do with the order of things loading in your page.

I suggest moving your script declarations from the `head` to just before your closing `body` tag to ensure they load as quickly as possible.